# Can't navigate to / and got undefined error instead

Tags: reactjs

When I delete a book from the BookDetails component, I get an undefined error ==> book is undefined. 
I tried to use navigate hook to redirect to the ReadingList component but I still got this error.
It's like BookDetails component was still rendered.

I post the codeSandbox here. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/reading-list-problem-suvz0?fbclid=IwAR3BSD8S92amT1i_Sgv6rO41rZnvwAO7vVg-940mC0hfSwAp9IwyCI0c49o

code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Router } from "@reach/router";
import BookContextProvider from "./context/bookContext";

import ReadingList from "./components/reading-list/ReadingList";
import BookDetails from "./components/reading-list/BookDetails";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BookContextProvider>
        <Router>
          <ReadingList path="/" />
          <BookDetails path="/books/:bookId" />
        </Router>
      </BookContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Can anyone have a look and give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

This is all happening asynchronously, meaning the component is still trying to re-render when the book doesn't exist. You can fix this by returning `null` or some other placeholder while the delete operation is happening:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { bookContext } from "../../context/bookContext";
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate } from "@reach/router";
const BookDetails = () => {
  //! usParams() renvoie l'object :bookId ::<BookDetails path="/books/:bookId" /> compris dans l'url.
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { books, deleteBook } = useContext(bookContext);
  const book = books.find(({ id }) => id.toString() === params.bookId);

  console.log(params);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.log(book.id);
    deleteBook(book.id);
    navigate("/");
  };

  if (!book) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Book details : </h1>
      <h2>{book.title}</h2>
      <p>author : {book.author}</p>
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>delete book</button>
      <Link to="/">back to list</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookDetails;
```

Alternatively, and possibly better, you could use a `Redirect` component in the render method when `book` doesn't exist. That would be potentially even nicer because you'd redirect home in case someone went to a non-existent book path regardless of whether they just deleted it.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { bookContext } from "../../context/bookContext";
import { Link, useParams, Redirect } from "@reach/router";
const BookDetails = () => {
  //! usParams() renvoie l'object :bookId ::<BookDetails path="/books/:bookId" /> compris dans l'url.
  const params = useParams();

  const { books, deleteBook } = useContext(bookContext);
  const book = books.find(({ id }) => id.toString() === params.bookId);

  const handleDelete = () => {
    console.log(book.id);
    deleteBook(book.id);
  };

  if (!book) {
    return <Redirect to="/" noThrow />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1>Book details : </h1>
      <h2>{book.title}</h2>
      <p>author : {book.author}</p>
      <button onClick={handleDelete}>delete book</button>
      <Link to="/">back to list</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BookDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. 
I'm gonna try to add a Redirect since as you said, it holds more logic.

Comment: okay, I'll add that implementation here (see updated response)

Comment: BTW, using `noThrow` is explained [here](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/100#issuecomment-415424987)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking into this but you were more quicker than me xD